# QList children - struct or custom classes derived from QObject?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian, qlist

I'm currently working on Qt application on Symbian platform. Application has an sqlite database and initial data is populated from txt files.

I'm implementing online update from data that comes in json format. So i would like to create generic functions in my db update class that takes `QList` of classes/structs and updated db from them. `QList` would be populated with objects either from txt, or json.

I already have the parsing in place, just considering what would be better in terms for performance:

1. Creating c++ structs and passing them (as objects hold only simple data) wrapped in `QList`
2. Creating custom classes derived from `QObject` and passing them as pointers in `QList` and then deleting everything with `qDeleteAll`
3. Any other way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on whether your classes are carrying behaviour or only state.

1. They carry behaviour.

   Then, a polymorphic class is in order, yes. Whether it needs to inherit from `QObject` is another question. Inherit from `QObject` *only* if you need its services (introspection, signals/slots, event handling). Otherwise, don't.

   As for `qDeleteAll()`: I wouldn't go there. Instead of naked pointers, use smart pointers, e.g. [`QSharedPointer`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsharedpointer.html). They keep track of the number of references to their payload, deleting it when the refcount falls to zero.

   In this case, don't use `QList`, but a more efficient container such as [`QVector`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qvector.html).
2. They carry only state.

   Then, a "dumb" `struct` may suffice. In this case, don't use `QList` as a container, but something more efficient, like `QVector` (don't forget to make good use of the `reserve()` method).

In general, try to avoid `QList<T>` for types `T` where `sizeof(T)>sizeof(void*)` and non-buildin/non-Qt-types, because [`QList` performance is degraded for these](http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/2010/07/29/sneak-preview-qlist-considered-harmful/).

Comment: They only carry state. Simple data taken from txt or json that needs to be inserted into db. I was thinking about QObject, because i though it would handle all my pointer worries :) But i think it would be ok to stick to QVector with struct? Considering that these are Symbian devices?

Comment: @meska: sure, `QVector` has the same memory layout as a C builtin-array, so it's maximally efficient (in space and time) if you don't add/remove elements in the middle. Even on Symbian :)

Comment: Ok, then last question : if i have ~ 50 elements that i want to pass in with QVector (Element - simple data 5 strings, 4 ints) can i get away without using pointers?

Comment: @meska: you mean `QVector<Element>` vs. `QVector<Element*>`? Definitely the former.